# How to check launch image is added in application using XCUITest?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest, xctestcase

i have implemented XCTest case for each module and i'm looking for how to know that launch Image is added in xcasset using xctest case.

Comment: I upvoted the Frankenstein's answer, but want to notice that UI Tests are not designed for checks like this. If you tell more about your task, maybe you will find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're going for here.

You could check if `LaunchImage` is available by checking the bundle images for the name.

```
func checkIfLaunchImageAvailable() -> Bool {
    for imageName in Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "png", inDirectory: nil) {
        if imageName.contains("LaunchImage"), UIImage(named: imageName) != nil {
            print("Launch image is available!")
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And could check using `XCTAssertTrue`:

```
XCTAssertTrue(checkIfLaunchImageAvailable)
```

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote and mark as right if it helped.